# How to run separate tests in parallel with NightwsatchJS

Tags: testing, ui-automation, nightwatch.js

The end goal is to run two **Different tests** in parallel. For example, to simulate a video conference between a teacher and a student.

I have tried searching for a solution; however, all the results I find are for running the same tests in parallel.

Is this possible with NightwatchJS? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, its possible. You should realise two tests in async functions and use Promise.all
Something like that
cons [first, second]=await Promise.all([ func1,func2]).

Where first its result of func1, second -func2. They will work parallel and promise wlll wait for ending them all.

Find right syntax on the site please, but Im sure, you have understood the idea.